# How to get the last value in the number counter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, counter

I have a number counter using js and some php snippet. Every 4 seconds the value of numer counter is adding +1. The start of running of the counter is from 7 am to 7 pm. I want to get the possible last count of the counter at 7 pm. And I will display the value from a certain time.

Can you please help to achieve this? [enter link description here](https://codepen.io/defotograf/pen/mmwazm)

PHP

```
$date           = date('G:i', time());
$server_time    = strtotime($date);
$initial_time   = 1493949600;
$target_time    = 1512007200;
$current_data_  = $row->cust_count + ($server_time - $initial_time)/($target_time - $initial_time) * 250000;
```

**JS**

```
(function ($){
    $.fn.countTo = function (options){
        options = options || {};

        return $(this).each(function (){
            //set options for current element
            var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults,{
                from: $(this).data('from'),
                to: $(this).data('to'),
                speed: $(this).data('speed'),
                //refreshInterval: $(this).data('refresh-interval'),
                decimals: $(this).data('decimals')
            }, options);

            var loops = Math.ceil(settings.speed / settings.refreshInterval),
            increment = (settings.to - settings.from) / loops; //how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update

            //references & variables that will change with each update
            var self = this,
                $self = $(this),
                loopCount = 0,
                value = settings.from,
                data = $self.data('countTo') || {};
              $self.data('countTo', data);

            //if an existing interval can be found, clear it first
            if (data.interval){
                clearInterval(data.interval);
            }

            data.interval = setInterval(updateTimer, settings.refreshInterval);
            render(value); //initialize the element with the starting value

            function updateTimer(){
        value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                render(value);
          if (typeof(settings.onUpdate) == 'function'){
            settings.onUpdate.call(self, value);
          }

                if (loopCount >= loops){
                    //remove the interval
                    $self.removeData('countTo');
                    clearInterval(data.interval);
                    value = settings.to;

                    if(typeof(settings.onComplete) == 'function'){
                        settings.onComplete.call(self, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            function render(value){
                var formattedValue = settings.formatter.call(self, value, settings);
                $self.html(formattedValue);
        $self.html(value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' '));
            }
        });
    };

    $.fn.countTo.defaults ={
        from: 0,               //the number the element should start at
        to: 0,                 //the number the element should end at
        speed: 1000,           //how long it should take to count between the target numbers
        refreshInterval: 100,  //how often the element should be updated
        decimals: 0,           //the number of decimal places to show
        formatter: formatter,  //handler for formatting the value before rendering
        onUpdate: null,        //callback method for every time the element is updated
        onComplete: null       //callback method for when the element finishes updating
    };

    function formatter(value, settings){
        return value.toFixed(settings.decimals);
    }
}(jQuery));

jQuery(function($){
  //custom formatting example
  $('.count-number').data('countToOptions',{
      formatter: function (value, options){
        return value.toFixed(options.decimals).replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
      }
  });

 // $('.timer').each(count); //start all the timers

  function count(options){
      var $this = $(this);
      options = $.extend({}, options || {}, $this.data('countToOptions') || {});
      $this.countTo(options);
  }
});

    var curr_date           = new Date()
var current_time        = (new Date).getTime()/1000
var current_hour        = (new Date).getHours()
var current_minutes     = curr_date.getMinutes()
var current_seconds     = curr_date.getSeconds()
var curr_time           = current_hour + ":" + current_minutes + ":" + current_seconds
var speed               = 60*60*24*30*3*40
//800000 is the value of $row->cust_count
var current_data = 800000 + (current_time - initial_time)/(target_time - initial_time) * 250000;
}

switch((new Date).getTime()){
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case 6:
        day = "Saturday";
}

jQuery(function($){
    if(curr_time >= '07:00:00' && curr_time <= '19:00:00'){
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: current_data,
            to: 1000000,                         
            speed: speed,
            refreshInterval: 1000,
            onUpdate: function(value){
                console.debug(this);
            },
            onComplete: function(value){
                console.debug(this);
            }
        });
    } else if(curr_time >= '17:00:01' && curr_time <= '6:59:59'){
        $('.timer').countTo({
            from: 800000, //here will be display the last count of the counter
            to: 800000 //here will be display the last count of the counter
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I think the question is a little bit unclear and too much unexplainable code.. _The start of running of the counter is from 7 am to 7 pm. I want to get the possible last count of the counter at 7 pm._ didn't understand the specific

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos What I mean is I want to get the last value of number counter at 7pm. E.g. if the counter starts in 800000 at 7 am and add the value is adding +1 in every 4 seconds and when the time reached at 7 pm, and the new value of counter is now 8150000. The new value will be displayed from 7:00:01 pm until 6:59:59 am without additional +1. It means the counting will be pause at 7pm

Comment: First of all i think right now it's adding +1 every 2 seconds. Secondly, what will hapen if you change `if(curr_time >= '07:00:00' && curr_time <= '19:00:00'){` to  `if(curr_time >= '07:00:00' && curr_time < '19:00:00'){` (removed the `<=`)

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos, when I removed `=` the value is missing

Comment: This question is really confusing. if you want to know the maximum value of the counter just check how many seconds are there between start time and end time, then divide by 4 and floor and add that to the initial count.

Can you tell us what are you trying to accomplish in the first place ?